# Netlogo: average distance between all turtles

Tags: netlogo

is there a convenient way to compute the average distance between all turtles at each step? I realize this can be computationally costly with many turtles, but I only need to compute this for 4 turtles.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you attempt to write some code involving `distance` and `mean`? If so, please include it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest might be to just create temporary links between all turtles, get the mean `link-length` for all those links, then remove those links.

Create a link breed to avoid messing with any other links you might have:

```
undirected-link-breed [ dists dist ]
```

Toy setup:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 3 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]    
  reset-ticks
end
```

Call this reporter to get the mean value:

```
to-report mean-dist
  ask turtles [
    create-dists-with other turtles
  ]
  let out mean [link-length] of dists

  ; Comment this out if you want to make sure
  ; that this works as intended
  ask dists [ die ]

  report out
end
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about links. Why did you suggest creating the links temporarily? I want to calculate (and plot) the mean distance at each tick.

Comment: @jlarsch - That would definitely work too (and be more efficient). You would have to rework it a little bit of course- in the example above, every time the `to-report` is called, it would create new `dists` between each turtle. So, it might be better to create `dists` between the turtles in a different procedure (and not have them `die`) and have the reporter just output `mean [link-length] of dists`. The example above was just to show the approach- your implementation will vary depending on your model.